# Highchart x-axis hide only values greater than 100

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Im using highchart reversed bar graph below
[image]

I want to hide any values on x-axis after 100. I do not want to set max value property to 100 because it decreases the graph area. I want same width for this graph but no values should be shown after 100. Meaning 120 shouldn't display, or any value greater than 100.

This is a standard highchart bar graph.

Below is the code

```
Highcharts.chart('container1', {
            chart: {
                type: 'bar',
                marginRight: 12
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            yAxis: {    
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {

                        if (CAT_percentageMaxValue >= 1.0) {
                            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 1) + '%';
                        }

                        else {

                            return this.value + '%';
                        }
                    }
                },

            title: { text: '' }

        },

            title: {
            text: 'Category Percentage',
            style: {
                // color: '#34495e',
                    fontWeight: '500',
                    fontSize: '16px'
            }
            },

        tooltip: {

                shared: false,

                formatter: function () {


                    return this.x + '<br/><span style="color:' + this.color + '">' + this.series.name + '</span>: <b>' + this.point.CategoryCount.toLocaleString(langIdFreqScoreCorrelation) + ' (' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1) + '%)</b><br/>'

                }
        },
        xAxis: {
                categories: labelData,
                gridLineWidth: 1

        },
        legend: { enabled: false },
        plotOptions: {

                bar: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        formatter: function () {
                            return "<span style='margin-bottom:5px;'>" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1) + "%</span>";
                        }
                    }
                }
        },
        series: [{
            color: colors[0],
            borderRadiusTopLeft: 3,
            borderRadiusTopRight: 3,
            name: 'Category Percentage',
            data: percentageData
        }],
        });
```

Comment: You should filter it before set series of chart. Can you share also code ?

Comment: @pc_coder there is no value greater than 100, whats the point of filtering ? I have added code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your requirement very well, but I assumed that it is related to the dataLabels position when the `yAxis.max` is set to 100. You can change the `overflow` and `crop` features to allow render dataLabels outside the plotArea.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L97re0q6/

```
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    overflow: 'allow',
    crop: false,
    formatter: function() {
      return "<span style='margin-bottom:5px;'>" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1) + "%</span>";
    }
  }
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.overflow

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.crop

Please confirm if it fits your requirements.